# How to make Browser Stack local testing work when not using Chrome plugin?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy, browserstack

My test website is behind corporate firewall. And i have been trying to using browser stack's local testing to test it. (https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing)

Using Chrome plugin has been straight forward. After installing plugin, i can immediately enter my test website url in remote browser and start testing.

Using BrowserStackLocal.exe is nightmare. I've tried adding proxy information using:

```
 --proxy-host <proxy_host> --proxy-port <proxy_port>
```

and:

```
 --local-proxy-host <browsermob_proxy_host> --local-proxy-port <browsermob_proxy_port> --local-proxy-user <proxy_username> --local-proxy-pass <proxy_password>
```

Even though the binary seems to connect to 'www.browserstack.com'

[image]

However, in IE, remote browser is NOT shown at all although 'local testing' shows a green check.

[image]

When we do automation testing using selenium, log also shows connection problem to 'hub-cloud.browserstack.com'.

[image]

We checked IT team, it seems browser stack is whitelisted.

Anyone have any suggestions? Any addition setup need to be performed after BrowserStackLocal binary is launched?

Actually i am not sure what happened after BrowserStackLocal is launched? How does my IE browser or selenium client know BrowserStackLocal exist, and route traffic via it?

Comment: Have you tried pinging the URL mentioned in the error from the machine running your protractor tests? "https://hub-cloud.browserstack.com"

Comment: You may also want to check if it works with the proxy configuration : var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
  usingServer('http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub').
  withCapabilities(capabilities).
  usingWebDriverProxy("proxy.org:8080").
  build();
Source: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node#proxy

Comment: @BountyHunter WebDriverProxy is the way to go, i just found it out. thank you for your comment.

Comment: Glad that helped. Do up vote my comment if it helped :) ! Also, post the working solution as answer for anyone who comes across similar issue in future.

Comment: @BountyHunter please post your answer as reply instead of comment so I can vote. Also this is only part of the solution. I do know what is wrong to the behavior in IE

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check if it works with the proxy configuration :

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder(). 
usingServer('hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub'). 
withCapabilities(capabilities). 
usingWebDriverProxy("proxy.org:8080"). build();
```

Source: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node#proxy